# Python 3 - How do I brute force a password for a PDF file using all possible 6-digit employee ID's?

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, brute-force, generate

I am practicing generating all possible 6-digit employee ID's (all having 900 at the beginning followed by all possible 6-digit numbers) to brute force a password for a PDF file named PS7_encrypted.pdf. So far, I have successfully generated all 6-digit pins (with 900 at the front) and stored them into a dictionary.txt file. I am working on a program that would read the file and brute force the PDF using that text file that has all the possible numbers. When I run the program however, I got no results, no password printed. What did I do wrong?
Code for generating the ID's:

```
#!/bin/python3
def genEmployeeID():
        with open('dictionary.txt', 'w') as wfile:
                for i in range(1000000):
                        wfile.write(f'900{i:06}' + "\n")
genEmployeeID()
```

Code for brute-forcing the PDF file:

```
#!/bin/python3
import PyPDF2
import sys
filename = 'PS7_encrypted.pdf' 
dictionary = 'dictionary.txt' 

password = None 
file_to_open = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(filename) 
with open(dictionary, 'r') as f: 
   for line in f.readlines(): 
         password = line.strip('\n') 
         try: 
               pss = bytes(password, 'utf-8')
               file_to_open.extractText(pwd = pss) 
               password = 'Password found: %s' % pss 
               print(password) 
         except: 
               pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `extractText` a function of this object? I can't find it in the [documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/PdfFileReader.html). Since you don't specify a specific exception to catch, I assume it passes right into the `except` block when it doesn't find that function. What you are looking for seems to be `decrypt(password)`.